# Issue with OAuth using signpost API on Netflix - OAuthCommunicationException

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, signpost

I tried to get Auth_url from retrieveRequestToken signpost API. It throws OAuthCommunicationException. When I used the same code for twitter(after changing consumer and provide), it works without issue. Please help me here. Thanks

```
public class NetflixTest {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String NETFLIX_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "http://api.netflix.com/oauth/request_token";
    public static final String NETFLIX_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "http://api.netflix.com/oauth/access_token";
    public static final String NETFLIX_AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://api-user.netflix.com/oauth/login";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("debug", "1");
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer("jw5pvuq766d6rf4m2pu2ft5r", "y8x3dhMFqz");    
        OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(NETFLIX_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
            NETFLIX_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, NETFLIX_AUTHORIZE_URL);

        try {
            String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, "http://mydomain.com/Netflix/");       
            System.out.println(authUrl);

        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getResponseBody());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your system time is synced to an NTP server. I've had issues with Netflix rejecting OAuth requests because my system time had drifted too far out of sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (connection.getRequestMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes("");
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
    } else {
        connection.connect();
    }
```

Changed sendRequest of DefaultOAuthProvider class as above. Seems like server is strict and expects some bytes when you do POST.